# Reading a paper on AI. Not sure what these notations mean: $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}(D;\mathbb{R}^{d_{\alpha}})$

Tags: analysis

I'm reading a paper and there is some notation I don't understand. I think it's common in set-theory but my google-searches haven't been fruitful.

The paper is very high level and probably above my understanding, but I want to give it a try nonetheless.

I'll probably need help with more later down in the line, but for now I'd like to understand this part:

> Let $D \subset \mathbb{R^{d}}$ be a bounded, open set, and $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}(D;\mathbb{R}^{d_{a}})$ and $\mathcal{U} = \mathcal{U}(D;\mathbb{R}^{d_{u}})$ be seperable Banach spaces of function taking values in $\mathbb{R}^{d_{a}}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{d_{u}}$ respectively

Specifically it's this part I don't get: $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}(D;\mathbb{R}^{d_{a}})$

I've looked into what Banach spaces are. Is $D$ the normed space? Does that then mean that $\mathbb{R}^{d_{a}}$ is the norm? (If so what would that norm actually mean?) Also why is $\mathcal{A}$ used recursively?

Paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.08895.pdf

Comment: can you share a link to the paper perhaps?

Comment: Of course. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.08895.pdf

Comment: okay, I think it is better to first edit your question with the full sentence from the paper: from "Let..." to "..respectively"

Comment: I've edited the question. Does it look better now?

Comment: Hard to be sure without context but it looks like  $\mathcal A, \mathcal U$ are just any two Banach spaces of functions from $D$ to some Euclidean space.  Certainly, the passage you quote doesn't tell us any more about them.  $D$ is just some bounded open set in a Euclidean space.